# Enable - Disable Table Result

Tags: php, html

I am making a phone directory for my school project and yet this my work so far. I want to hide the table header (Last name, First Name, etc)
 then view it after i got the result.
[image: Before Search. Header is view(I want to hide it)]

[image: After Search. I want to view the header]

This images are before and after I search names 
and here are my codes:

```
    <table class="gridtable">
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Telephone Number</th>
    <th>Network</th>
    <th>Something Wrong?</th>
```

This is my table header

```
include 'database.php';

$lname = "";
$fname = "";

if(isset($_POST['lname'])  || (isset($_POST['fname']))){ $fname = $_POST['fname'];     $lname = $_POST['lname']; }

if(!isset($_POST['fname']) || ($_POST['lname'])) ;

$vars = array('lname');
$verified = TRUE;
foreach($vars as $v) {
if(!isset($_POST[$v]) || empty($_POST[$v])) {
  $verified = FALSE;
}
}
if(!$verified) {
exit();
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1 WHERE lname like '%$lname%' AND fname like     '%$fname%' ");
```

Here is where I echo my results

```
if($count = mysql_num_rows($result)){


echo "<p class=\"count\"> <b>$count </b> Results  for <b><i>\" $lname $fname \"</i></b>   </p>";
}
else 
echo "<p class=\"count\"> No Result for - <b><i>\" $lname $fname  \"</i></b></p>";

while(@$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo

"<tr>" .
"<td><b>" . $row['lname'] . "</b></td>" .
"<td><b>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row['telnum'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row['network'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . 
"<input type = \"submit\" value= \"Report\" class= \"classname \" name= \"report\">" . 
"</tr>";



}
?>
```

Comment: and the question is...

Comment: I want to hide my table header before i make a search then view it after i make the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your table in the condition

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { //Process if SQL returns more than 0 rows
   //Table code here
}
```

> Warning: You are using `mysql_()` which are deprecated, consider using
>   `mysqli_()` or PDO instead.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the reply Mr. Alien I will revise my codes now. Im looking forward in using mysqli.

Comment: Mr. Alien can you please clarify your answer, I'm having trouble revising my code. Can you post the codes. Thank you Sir

Comment: @SiDerf It's not that tough, just place the table headers and the loop inside that condition ..thats all you need to do

Comment: Mr. Alien sorry for that Sir, I've got the codes right now and it works great. Than you so much sir! You fixed my problem

Comment: Can I get your email-add or facebook name sir? If it's ok

Comment: @SiDerf E-mail id's on my Stack profile page, I don't use fb, it's crap